# Laravel 4 Query Builder (Joins)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have these tables in my database, namely "airport" and "route", the id of "airport" is a foreign key in "route" (i.e. Origin, Destination).

```
Airport
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
|  id   | airportcode |  Location             | 
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
|   1   |   CEB       | Cebu                  | 
|   2   |   MAN       | Manila                |
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+

Routes
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
|   id  | Origin      |  Destination          | 
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
|   1   |   1         | 2                     | 
|   2   |   2         | 1                     |
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

So far, this is my query in my Controller and it's only returning the "Origin, Destination"

```
DB::table('airport')
    ->join('route', 'airport.id','=','route.Origin')
    ->join('route', 'airport.id','=','route.Destination')
    ->select('route.Origin', 'route.Destination')
    ->get();
```

What I would like to do is this:

`SELECT 'airport.Location' from airport, route WHERE 'route.Origin' = 'airport.id' AND 'route.Destination' = 'airport.id"`.

Any suggestions will do!

Comment: Can you clarify what you're hoping to obtain from your query? Are you looking for all the locations reachable from a particular location, i.e. a query for "Cebu" would return "Manila"?

Comment: I'd like to obtain the "Locations" of an airport with the use of the columns "Origin" and "Destination" in the route...

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear on your intentions...can you demonstrate a sample query and your intended result?

Comment: It's something like this...(sorry if my query is bad)

SELECT 'airport.Location' from airport, route WHERE 'route.Origin' = 'airport.id' AND 'route.Destination' = 'airport.id"

I thank you for your cooperation even though my question is not clear, thanks!

Comment: please edit your question and mark what you want exactly, and even better show a sample result from the desired query.

Answer (score 0):

So - you want to pull out the model for a specific airport id but only if it goes to the specified destination?

Your first query will only return the two columns as that's what you told it to return

You can get the airport easily by:

```
Airport::find($id);
```

Where $id is the id from a user input for example and should be the key. Find will return a collection

You could also do:

```
Airport::where('id','=', $id)->first() //will return the first record - you could also use ->get() to return a collection
```

Then if you have a join in your Airport model such as ->hasMany you could then do:

```
Airport::where('id','=', $id)
    ->with('routes')
    ->get()
```

Which will return the airport with the related routes model attached to it

You can then take that a stage further and query the relationship by:

```
Airport::find($id)->routes()->where('destination','=',$dest_id);
```

I think that should do the trick - as long as you create the relationship correctly in the models

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a **select** query make sure that you have mentioned all the fields you want...

`it's only returning the "Origin, Destination"` because you have mentioned only those two in your select query.

try something like...

```
DB::table('route')
   ->select('route.Origin', 'route.Destination','airport.Location')
   ->leftjoin('airport',  function($join)
                        {
                            $join->where('airport.id',array('route.Origin','route.Destination'));   
                         // I haven't used it, if any errors pls comment
                        })

   ->get();
```

hope this helps you...